# How to query change tracking from a specific time frame

Tags: sql, sql-server, change-tracking

I wanted to take note of all the changes that occurred to a given table so I decided to set up change tracking on this table. If I want to query all the changes that occurred within this table, I would use the code below:

```
select * from changetable(changes databasename.tablename,1) as chtbl
```

Is there a way where I can track a specific time frame? For example, all of the changes that occurred yesterday. I'm thinking that this might be able to be accomplished by replacing the tracking version with a variable but I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/track-history-data-changes-using-sql-server-2016-system-versioned-temporal-tables/